# Issues using compare lists in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame in pandas with one of the column types being a list on int, like so:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([[1,2,3,[4,5]],[6,7,8,[9,10]]], columns=['a','b','c','d'])
>>> df
   a  b  c        d
0  1  2  3   [4, 5]
1  6  7  8  [9, 10]
```

I'd like to build a filter using d, but the normal comparison operations don't seem to work:

```
>>> df['d'] == [4,5]
0    False
1    False
Name: d, dtype: bool
```

However when I inspect row by row, I get what I would expect

```
>>> df.loc[0,'d'] == [4,5]
True
```

What's going on here? How can I do list comparisons?

Comment: Your first comparison won't work there is no conversion from a series to a list for the comparison. The second one works because the element content is returned which is the list so a comparison can be made. Could you explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @EdChum `d['d']` returns a `Series` of `list`'s, the operation then compares each element to the right hand side. I would expect the return series to be `[True,False]` as the first row at column `d` has the same list, whereas the second does not. Instead I get `[false, false]` which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It may be a bug, unsure about this one, the presence of the list object could be confusing it, maybe because lists cannot be hashed. If you instead stored a dict then the comparison works: `df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,{'a':[4,5]}],[6,7,8,{'a':[9,10]}]], columns=['a','b','c','d'])   df.d == {'a':[4,5]}` I'm not suggesting that this is a solution

Comment: It's not a bug, it's that the list syntax is used for comparison of the entire series.  It makes sense because you're not comparing each element to `[4,5]`, you're comparing the first element to 4 (which it's not) and the second element to 5 (which it's not).  Thus: `[False, False]`.  If you want similar behaviour, you could use tuples, I guess: `df["d"] == (4,5)` would work the way you want it.  `pandas` doesn't really support nonscalar entries.

Comment: Similarly it also works if you stored tuples instead of a list

Comment: DSM is correct if you did this :`df.d == [[4,5],[4,5]]` then it does what you expect but the syntax is unwieldly

Comment: @DSM okay that makes sense, tuples seem like the way to go.

Comment: The problem is if you save the tuple to a mongodb and then read it back to a DataFrame, or actually save/load it passing through any kind of JSON format. It will be converted to a list. Using the `apply` method seems to be the best workaround for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a curious issue, it probably has to do with the fact that list are not hashable
I would go for apply:

```
df['d'].apply(lambda x: x == [4,5])
```

Of course as suggested by DSM, the following works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,(4,5)],[6,7,8,(9,10)]], columns=['a','b','c','d'])
df['d'] == (4,5)
```

Another solution is use `list comprehension`:

```
df[[x == [4, 5] for v in df['col2']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you wish to keep your "series of lists" structure, you can convert your series to tuples for comparison purposes only. This is possible via [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
>>>>df['d'].apply(tuple) == (4, 5)

0     True
1    False
Name: d, dtype: bool
```

However, note that none of the options available for a series of lists are vectorised. You are advised to split your data into numeric series before performing comparisons.